# protractor and appium - cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, appium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to lunch some selenium tests on an android device.
All the connection seams to work, as on the device i can see chrome opening and then the url change to data;

but after the url changes, everything stops saying

> [launcher] Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Q' of undefined at module.exports (C:\src\angular-test\node_modules\wd-bridge\lib\wd-bridge.js:6:13)

I think it is related to wdBridge, as if i check wd-bridge,js, Q looks like this:

```
var Q = wd.Q;
```

I have no idea why its not working.

My protractor config file is the following:

```
"use strict";

exports.config = {
    specs: ['e2e/*.js'],
    framework: 'jasmine',
    capabilities: {
        'appium-version': '',
        'platformName': 'Android',
        'platformVersion': '6.0',
        'deviceName': 'Android Device',
        'autoWebView': true,
        'app': "C:/src/angular-test/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk",
        'udid': '',
        'fullReset': true,
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
        print: function () {
        }
    },
    onPrepare: function () {

        var DisplayProcessor = require('../node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter/src/display-processor');
        var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

        function TimeProcessor(options) {
        }

        function getTime() {
            var now = new Date();
            return now.getHours() + ':' +
                now.getMinutes() + ':' +
                now.getSeconds()
        }

        TimeProcessor.prototype = new DisplayProcessor();
        TimeProcessor.prototype.displaySuite = function (suite, log) {
            return getTime() + ' - ' + log;
        };
        TimeProcessor.prototype.displaySuccessfulSpec = function (spec, log) {
            return getTime() + ' - ' + log;
        };
        TimeProcessor.prototype.displayFailedSpec = function (spec, log) {
            return getTime() + ' - ' + log;
        };
        TimeProcessor.prototype.displayPendingSpec = function (spec, log) {
            return getTime() + ' - ' + log;
        };

        // add jasmine spec reporter
        var reporter = new SpecReporter({
            customProcessors: [TimeProcessor]
        });

        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);

        var wd = require('wd'),
            wdBridge = require('wd-bridge')(wd);
        wdBridge.initFromProtractor(exports.config);

    },
    //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub' //For mobile devices
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub' //For desktop
};
```

Any help, as always, is really appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself.
Here's what i did:

Starting from the code above, as mentioned, Q was undefined.
This was because `var Q = wd.Q` that can be found inside wd-bridge.js file inside the node module folder is inside a function that needs 2 parameters.

I changed my protractor.config.js file like this:

```
"use strict";

var wd = require('wd');
var protractor = require ('protractor');
var wdBridge = require('wd-bridge')(protractor,wd);

exports.config = {
    specs: ['e2e/*.js'],
    framework: 'jasmine',
    capabilities: {
        'appium-version': '',
        'platformName': 'Android',
        'platformVersion': '6.0',
        'deviceName': 'Android Device',
        'autoWebView': true,
        'app': "C:/src/angular-test/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk",
        'udid': '',
        'fullReset': true,
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
        print: function () {
        }
    },
    onPrepare: function () {

        var DisplayProcessor = require('../node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter/src/display-processor');
        var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

        function TimeProcessor(options) {
        }

        function getTime() {
            var now = new Date();
            return now.getHours() + ':' +
                now.getMinutes() + ':' +
                now.getSeconds()
        }

        TimeProcessor.prototype = new DisplayProcessor();
        TimeProcessor.prototype.displaySuite = function (suite, log) {
            return getTime() + ' - ' + log;
        };
        TimeProcessor.prototype.displaySuccessfulSpec = function (spec, log) {
            return getTime() + ' - ' + log;
        };
        TimeProcessor.prototype.displayFailedSpec = function (spec, log) {
            return getTime() + ' - ' + log;
        };
        TimeProcessor.prototype.displayPendingSpec = function (spec, log) {
            return getTime() + ' - ' + log;
        };

        // add jasmine spec reporter
        var reporter = new SpecReporter({
            customProcessors: [TimeProcessor]
        });

        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);

        wdBridge.initFromProtractor(exports.config);

    },
    //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub' //For mobile devices
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub' //For desktop
};
```

it is now working perfectly.

**Note: If you have `wd`, `wdBridge` or `protractor` modules not found, you need to install them NOT GLOBALLY (for example, `npm install wd` instead of `npm install -g wd`)**

Hope this can help you out.